# Ignore Quoting while reading CSV using Super CSV

Tags: java, supercsv

I working a CSV reader project  and using Super csv to process csv files. I ran into an issue where the log that I was parsing was using the quote character to denote inches (example: Foo".) This caused me to miss out on processing 100k lines from the file having same number of lines since this quote mismatch occurred in first row it self. Please help me resolving this because this is creating lot of other bugs in project.

Comment: You can't ignore quotes when reading CSV, because quotes are part of some of the formats called CSV. Are you sure your file is correctly formatted?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `size in inches marked by double quote` always within the same column in your CSV?

If so, just use `StrReplace("\"", "", new ParseDouble());` for that column.